# Libgdx Table align item

Tags: libgdx

So I've used `Table` class a lot before, I don't know if the newer version of libgdx changed something(haven't code with libgdx in a while) or I'm missing something but I'm pretty sure this code should align the `Image` to the top-left of the `Table`

```
Table t = new Table();
t.setSize(500,300);

t.add(image).width(50).height(50).left().top();

stage.addActor(t);
```

It adds the `Image` to the center of the table and I want it to the top-left

I've tried this too

```
t.add(image).width(50).height(50).align(Align.topLeft);
```

and

```
t.defaults().left().top();
```

I don't want it to expand the cell, I just want to align it as it is.

I've tried it with `expand()` and it aligns it correctly so I'm assuming this aligns the `Actor` to top-left of the `Cell` but how do I align the `Cell` to top-left of the `Table`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should have used `Table.left().top()` instead of `Cell.left().top()` which I don't remember ever doing this, buy hey, it makes sense.

```
Table t = new Table();
t.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),300);
t.left().top();
        
t.add(image).width(100).height(100);
```